# Cubic composition algebras

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Is there any analogue of composition algebras for cubic (and possibly higher degree) forms?

Concretely, in quadratic case we start from a quadratic map $Q: A \to k$ with polarisation $B$ and search for a multiplication $\mu: A \otimes A \to A$ satisfying composition identity: $$B(x, y)B(z, w) - 2(B(xz, yw) + B(xw, yz)) = 0.$$ I'm writing it in slightly unconventional form to make apparent the fact that defining identity is vanishing of particular $(0, 4)$-tensor.

We can try to construct *something* starting from a cubic map $F: A \to k$. But what is $\mu$, should it be algebra (unlikely), ternary algebra or some more bizarre structure like a $(3, 2)$-tensor? Which combination(s) of $F$ and $\mu$ should be taken as relation(s)?

Probably easier question: what is "linear composition algebra"?